Proposition (0.1.4.3) in Tamme's Introduction to Etale Cohomology
Proposition 1.4.3, page 7 in Tamme's book, says (among other things) that: given two categories $\cal C$ and $\cal C'$, with $\cal C'$ abelian and AB-$3$, if $\cal C'$ has a generator $Z$ then also the category $\mathrm{Fun}(\mathcal C,\mathcal C')$ has a family of generators.
In order to obtain a family of generators in $\mathrm{Fun}(\mathcal C,\mathcal C')$, one constructs a functor $Z_A:\cal C\to C'$ for each object $A$ in $\mathcal C'$. In the text such $Z_A$, on the objects, is defined in this way: $$Z_A(-):=\bigoplus_{\mathrm{Hom}(-,A)}Z.$$
However immediately after it is proven that there is a bijection $\mathrm{Hom}(Z,F(A))\to \mathrm{Nat}(Z_A,F)$ for every functor $F$ in $\mathrm{Fun}(\mathcal C,\mathcal C')$; here (precisely in the last line of page 8) it seems that, in the sum, the copies of $Z$ are indexed by morphisms with domain $A$, not codomain. Also in the definition of $Z_A$ on morphisms, if $A$ is kept at the codomain I get a contravariant functor $Z_A$ while $F$ is assumed covariant. In fact later in the text, in remark 2.1.3 page 31, we construct the generators of the category of presheaves over $\cal C$ by $$Z_A(-):=\bigoplus_{\mathrm{Hom}(-,A)}\mathbb Z,$$ but a presheaf is actually a contravariant functor $\cal C\to Ab$ so it makes sense. Do you confirm instead that the definition of $Z_A$ at page 8 should be $$Z_A(-):=\bigoplus_{\mathrm{Hom}(A,-)}Z?$$
